# How to search files via the file selection dialogue? (keyboard shortcut)

Tags: shortcut-keys, filemanager, search

Clicking on a shortcut folder and typing directly afterwards allows for searching for files.

And in Windows, the file selection manager has much of the real Windows Explorer functionality, including a powerful file searcher no Linux file manager can match so far.

Is there any other way to access search?

- Ctrl+L does access the file path bar.
- Ctrl+K and F6 do not work for accessing search.

**Is there any other way?**

Comment: No, there isn't. Linux distros never adopted Windows bad practices.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia The Windows search feature however is outstanding.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia So the only way to access search is to click on the shortcut folder and type search immediately after that, which forces me to create a bookmark each time I need to search a directory?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Hopefully, SearchMonkey tries to compete with Windows Explorer search. SearchMonkey  works on Windows **and** Linux.

Comment: Re. *"including a powerful file searcher no Linux file manager can match so far"*, how many Linux file managers have you examined and in how much depth?

Comment: @DKbose I have tried Natulious, Dolphin, Caja, Thunar, Nemo and that one included in PartedMagic.

Comment: Have you heard about Catfish & Baloo?

Comment: @DKbose I use catfish already. It is really fast but lacks advanced search parameters and drag&drop support. But CatFish is really quick, reliable and supports filtering by filetype. I will check out Baloo. But CatFish is not the file opening dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

1) For Nautilus (Ubuntu GNOME) you can use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> then type filename or part of filename.

2) For GNOME at all you can use in any place of shell: click Activities (<kbd>Win</kbd> = <kbd>Super</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>) or Applications (<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) then type filename or part of filename.